# How to bring UV from another object in blender 3.0 geometry nodes?

Tags: geometry-nodes

I want to make a hologram earth but separate into different objects(lands/boundaries/sea/etc), and build from the same earth object.

Here are my questions.

For using image texture. Is this the only way to bring UV into geometry nodes by Group Input like in the picture below? Looks like it can only bring the current object's own UV.
If it is, then how to bring UV from another object?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is currently (Blender 3+) the only way.

If you want to process the *UV map* of another object, you proceed in the same way.

However, you also include the object with the node `Object Info` in your node group.

As you can see, the spreadsheet displays the *UV data* of the additionally included cylinder.

[image]